# Please just tell me what the error is with my weather application(beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried making weather app

```js
var Weather = angular.module('Weather', []);
var faren;
var cel;
var wed;
var temp;
var loc;
var wind;
var ktemp;

Weather.controller("locat", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
  $http.get("url").then(function(response) {
    $scope.location = response.data;
    $scope.locationtwo = response.data.country;
  });
});


Weather.controller("lat&long", function($http, $rootscope) {
  $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=23&lon=55&appid=822eb616acf86279db40fadfbddf1b9d").then(function(response) {
    $scope.today = response.data.main.temp;
  });
});

Weather.controller("chgdg", function($scope) {
  $scope.mycf = function(response) {
    var faren = Math.round(today) * (9 / 5) - 459.67;
    var cel = Math.round(today - 273);

    if (cel === true) {
      $scope.today = response.faren;
    } else {
      $scope.today = response.cel;
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Weather">

<head>
  <title>Know your weather</title>
</head>

<body class="back">
  <div ng-controller="lat&long">
    //Actual weather// {{today}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="locat">
    {{location}} {{locationtwo}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="chgdeg">
    <button ng-click="mycf()">C/F</button>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="develop">Developed by = S.S</div>
    <div class="langs">Created by: HTML,CSS,ANGULARJS</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with it 
I have tried hard and I have come up with nothing 
I am still a beginner so I am definitely quite not sure what is wrong 
It seems to display the only the html 
Nothing from my angularjs seems to work
Please tell me what wrongs with my angularjs

Update : I had put my angular js code in 3 online syntax validator . All of them have approved that it is sytactically correct except a few unnecessary errors . 
But still my application does not work . Will you please just read my code and tell me is there something I need to change . Even try checking if the code is working for you .

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: Please start with your browser console, do you see any errors?

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong with it, how are we to know?

Comment: Don't say it "seems not to work" and leave it as that. We know that by the fact that you wrote the question. **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: The reason for the ambiguity of the question is I could'nt pinpoint exactly where my code seems to go wrong . I knew my code is wrong somewhere but I couldn't point it out . That is why I have posted my entire application code here so the professionals could at least tell me the error . I do not want the complete solved code just want to know what my error is . As still a beginner I am still struggling so just a little help would be very much appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controllers are written a little wrong. You have to pass an array as the second argument to your `.controller` method, and then include providers to it before passing them to function, like this:

```
angular
  .module('moduleName')
  .controller("ControllerName", [parameters, function(parameters) {
    // Controller's code here
})];
```

Here is example for your first controller:

```
Weather.controller("locat", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
    $http.get("url").then(function(response) {
        $scope.location = response.data;
        $scope.locationtwo = response.data.country;
    });
})];
```

Just use this pattern for all of your controllers.

Or, if you like, you can use the following structure:

```
Weather.controller("locat", ["$scope", "$http", LocatCtrl]);

function LocatCtrl($scope, $http)
    var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
    $http.get("url").then(function(response) {
        $scope.location = response.data;
        $scope.locationtwo = response.data.country;
    });
};
```

I prefer the second way, because the code looks more readable.

And there is an error with `$rootScope` in your second controller, it should be camelCase.

And in you JS code, the third controller name is `chgdg`, but in HTML you misspelled, it's `chgdeg` in HTML. "chgdg !== chgdeg".

For more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Thanks to @Hadi for help in comments!

Comment: @ShumailaShaikh, did it help you?

Comment: Your answer not resolve OP problem. It's just minify safe.

Comment: @Hadi, why not? The OP's controllers were define a little wrong, i have corrected it in the first part of my answer. The second part, yes, just a minify safe.

Comment: @Hadi, yes, with `$rootScope` too. Check out the first code example from here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller. OP's controller were define wrong. And yes, thanks for paying attention on `$rootScope`, i missed it.

Comment: and also for last controller `chgdeg` name. it's miss match with controller name in view.  `chgdeg != chgdg`  see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vZ7MQOV7X1KlonJmRmTN?p=preview)

Comment: @Hadi, oh, yes, thanks a lot for your help! I'll update the answer in few minutes

Comment: Controllers DO NOT require the second parameter to be an array. The second parameter as an array deals with minification and is only one of many possible ways to min-safe your code.

Comment: Thank you so much @commercial Suicide for your help .  I will make all the above mentioned edits and see if it works .

Comment: The code still does not work . I have tried everything I could . I ran my code through online code validators and it comes up as  syntactically correct . I do not know what else I can do to fix it .

Comment: @ShumailaShaikh, looks like your forgot to include your app file to HTML after importing Angularjs from CDN. After this row: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">  </script>` include your app like this: `<script src="path/to/your/app/file"></script>`

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I have already included my app file in the application  hwile it is not been shown in the code above and still it does'nt seem to work .

Comment: @ShumailaShaikh, remove all other controllers and start from building only one controller.